# Librería Android-WVersionManager, duda de implementacion

Tags: android

Estimados, estoy siguiendo la implementación de la librería Android-WVersionManager como figura en su sitio de GitHUb (https://github.com/winsontan520/Android-WVersionManager), pero lamentablemente no comprendo la sección en donde me solicita una URL (versionManager.setVersionContentUrl), ¿es posible si me pueden orientar en la implementación de esta librería? de una manera general no específicamente en la sección de la URL.

Resultado Mostrado logcat.

```
05-02 19:13:33.074 4910-4910/app.cooperativa.cl D/WVersionManager: status = 200
05-02 19:13:33.074 4910-4910/app.cooperativa.cl D/WVersionManager: result = {"version_code":35,"content":"Version 3.5 <p>Nuevas Caracteristicas:</p><li>Mejoras en Diseño</li><li>Mejoras en Validaciones</li>"}
```

De antemano estimados muchas gracias nuevamente por todo.

Comment: Buenas yo te recomiendo mejor la AppUpdater https://github.com/javiersantos/AppUpdater y para valorar la app https://github.com/kobakei/Android-RateThisApp, miratelas se veen más faciles de implementar a primera vista

Answer (score 0):

Esta librería implementa un flujo para la comprobación de nuevas versiones de tu aplicación y te invita a actualizar. En este caso y leyendo un poco la documentación, debes proveer una UR que responda la siguiente estructura:

```
{
    version_code: 20,
    content: "Version 2.0 <p>New features:</p><li>Added feature A</li><li>Added feature B</li><li>Added feature C</li>"
}
```

En el ejemplo de la aplicación te resuelve la siguiente URL:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/42536739/WVersionManager/version_2.txt

Saludos.

Comment: Gracias CarkXP, esa URL pienso que debe contener un archivo en formato json?

Comment: Efectivamente, es un archivo JSON con esos 2 parámetros. Como recomendación `version_code` debe coincidir con el versionCode de tu aplicación.

Comment: entiendo, entonces el flujo funciona de la siguiente manera: la librería está leyendo el archivo especificado .json, en donde yo registro lo que viene en la nueva versión (agregar o actualizar alguna funcionalidad, etc), y según lo que ahí incluyo envía mensaje de alerta al usuario una ves que detecta alguna modificación?

Comment: Adicional a esto, de qué forma puedo probar lo realizado?

Comment: según su documentación debería usa el siguiente listener:

`versionManager.setOnReceiveListener(new OnReceiveListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onReceive(int status, String result) {
        // implement your own compare logic here
        return false; // return true if you want to use library's default logic & dialog
    }
});`

Comment: ok muchas gracias, si observas edité mi pregunta agregando unas líneas del logcat, ¿es positivo el resultado?